# Concatenate Row and Column names from Data.Frame

Tags: r

Is there a way to concatenate the row and column names from an existing data.frame into a new data frame.  For example, I have column names of (A, B, C) and row names of (1, 2, 3) and I would like to combine these into a 3x3 matrix [A1, B1, C1; A2, B2, C2; A2, B2, C2].  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `outer()` function can help:

```
> cn <- c("A","B","C")
> rn <- c("1","2","3")
> outer(cn, rn, function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep=""))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A1" "A2" "A3"
[2,] "B1" "B2" "B3"
[3,] "C1" "C2" "C3"
>
```

Comment: Or short version `outer(cn, rn, paste, sep="")`

Comment: This is one of those moments when I bless the existence of `...` function argument!